# SpecFlow - No matching step definition found for one or more steps

Tags: .net, bdd, specflow

New to SpecFlow

If I set up my Given, When and Then scenario and do not pass arguments, everything works just fine:

Given Login to WebQA

```
 [Given(@"Login to WebQA")]
    public void LoginToWebQA()
    {
```

All of the reading on the web indicates that all I have to do is change the attribute to include a regular expression and add the argument to the method as follows:

```
 [Given(@"Login to '(.*)'")]
    public void LoginTo(string url)
    {enter code here
```

But when I do so, re-compile and run the  test, I get the following error:

```
No matching step definition found for one or more steps.
```

[Binding]
public class StepDefinitions
{
    [Given(@"Login to WebQA")]
    public void GivenLoginToWebQA()

Thanks in advance

Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try without single quotes:

```
 [Given(@"Login to (.*)")]
    public void LoginTo(string url)
    {enter code here
```

Here is random code sample I use:

Given so and so

When so and so

Then result description should be [test description]

```
[Binding]
public class AssertionSteps
{
    [Then(@"result description should be (.*)")]
    public void ThenResultDescriptionShouldBe(string hitDescription)
    {
        //here I also clean up the param value to remove []
    }   
}
```